# Экспорт карты из Конструктора в GeoJSON

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, geojson

Как через АПИ произвести выгрузку карты в формате .geojson?

Вручную из Конструктора - понятно, но надо автоматизировать процесс периодической выгрузки карт и их загрузки в проект. Не могу найти ни примера, ни описания в документации.

Comment: Такой возможности нет, карты Конструктора можно экспортировать только вручную через интерфейс.

Comment: Увидел ваш комментарий отвечу тут.
Я работал только с конструктором. Поэтому как делать это через АПИ я не знаю, мне кажется такой возможности нет

Comment: @Reni Ваш комментарий вполне можно переделать в ответ.

Comment: @0xdb, а можно немного подробней? Или имеются в виду программы, позволяющие записать действия пользователя и повторять их в дальнейшем?

Comment: Посмотрел Конструктор на предмет возможной работы через какой-нибудь автокликер, но в списке карт нет ни фиксированного порядка, ни поиска карты...

Answer (score 0):

Такой возможности нет, карты Конструктора можно экспортировать только вручную через интерфейс.